# Azure AD OIDC Passport Strategy pid:2179,level:40 Production environments should always validate the issuer

Tags: node.js, azure-authentication, passport-azure-ad

Hello i am trying to implement Azure authentication by following the tutorial provided by Microsoft https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-nodeexpressapp . I registered the app succesfully and replace fill in the client secret and the app-id in the .env file.

why i run the app. It returns:

```
{"name":"AzureAD: OIDC Passport Strategy","hostname":"webapp-virtual-machine","pid":2202,"level":40,"msg":"Production environments should always validate the issuer.","time":"2020-02-01T15:23:20.190Z","v":0
```

Which is an hour earlier then the dutch local time. I also change the region within the Azure portal. But that does not change the output.

Can you please help me!

Manny thanks

Erik

Comment: After changes, Did you restart the application?

Comment: Yes, multiple times, even reboot the machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Z** Time is **UTC** Time, only by a different name.

So what you get ("2020-02-01T15:23:20.190Z") is a **UTC** time.

But the dutch local time is **CET** time, which should be **UTC +1**.

You need to use **Prefer: outlook.timezone** header to specify the time zone for start and end times in the response. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-headers).

Or you can also convert the **UTC** time to **CET** time by yourself in your code.